# c++ stl iterators

Tags: c++, stl, set

I am getting a lot of errors trying to use an iterator for three dimensional vector of sets of ints. See the following code (which is just select pieces, because the whole thing is too long; I think this should be enough to see what is wrong, but let me know if it isn't):

```
vector<vector<vector<set<int> > > > particles_celllist;
vector<vector<vector<set<int> > > >::iterator cell_iter;
map<int,map<int,Particle> > particle_grid;

for (cell_iter=particles_celllist[wx][wy][wz].begin();cell_iter!=particles_celllist[wx][wy][wz].end();cell_iter++)
{
    double distance_to_cell=sqrt(pow(particles[*cell_iter].position().y()-(wy)*ygridlength,2)+
        pow(particles[*cell_iter].position().z()-(wz)*zgridlength,2));
    if (distance_to_cell<input_data.diam_large())
    {
        particle_grid[box_counter][*cell_iter]=particles[*cell_iter];
    }
}
```

Note: wx, wy, wz, and box_counter are ints, ygridlength and zgridlength are doubles, and Particle::position::y (or ::z) and input_data::diam_large return doubles.

I get a multitude of errors:

> no match for operator "=" in
>   "cell_iter=particles_celllist[wx][wy][wz].begin()"
>
> no match for operator "!=" in
>   "cell_iter!=particles_celllist[wx][wy][wz].end()"
>
> no match for operator "[]" whenever I used [*cell_iter] to call
>   something

I get the feeling like the error somehow stems from the iterator itself, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Please include declaration of `particles_celllist`

Comment: @thekashyap First line of the code section `vector<vector<vector<set<int> > > > particles_celllist;`

Comment: my bad.. I see the question is already answered now.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `set<int>::iterator cell_iter;`. Just look again carefully at whose `begin()` function you're calling.

In C++11 you would of course just have said

```
auto cell_iter = particles_celllist[wx][wy][wz].begin()
```

and never noticed that this is hard :-)

Comment: wow...that easy huh? Seems to work fine now. Every time I had used something like this, I guess I just did it a slightly different way that worked fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In C++03 I would just have done `std::for_each(particles_celllist[wx][wy][wz].begin(),particles_celllist[wx][wy][wz].end(), Action())` and never even noticed it was hard. In fact that is still how I would do it in C++11 (though Action may now be a lambda (which is hard(sort of))).

Comment: @LokiAstari: I wasn't going to address the larger design. For your situation, I'd prefer `for (auto & c : particles_celllist[wx][wy][wz]) { /* ... */ }` in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

`particles_celllist[wx][wy][wz]` is of type `set<int>`, so `particles_celllist[wx][wy][wz].begin()` is of type `set<int>::iterator`